# SpringSecurity implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector - throws are not thrown and loop of requests coming

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have an application with spring security 2.5.+ with outh2 and I need to create custom introspector. All is fine but throws are not thrown in Introspector class and I am not sure why.

This is my filterChain:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, Introspector introspector) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(
                    new AccessTokenFilter(authenticationManager(http, introspector), authenticationFailureHandler()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    return http.getOrBuild();
}
```

in AccessTokenFilter:

```
public class AccessTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public AccessTokenFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler) {
        super(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE);
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        String authorizationHeader = extractAuthorizationHeaderAsString(request);
        if (authorizationHeader == null) { throw new InvalidTokenException("The provided Authorization header is empty"); }
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new BearerTokenAuthenticationToken(authorizationHeader));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (failed instanceof AccessTokenRequiredException) {
            throw failed;
        } else {
            super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
        }
    }
```

}

And in Introspector:

```
public class Introspector implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {


    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspect(String token) {

       if (token == null) {
         throw new AuthenticationException("Token is null.");
       }
       ....
    }
}
}
```

but throw is not thrown and callback is sent to introspect method, how can I throw an error and return 401 when the token is null?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem was in filterChain - authenticationManager was registered twice and bean wasn't used - correct one:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(
                    new AccessTokenFilter(authenticationManager, authenticationFailureHandler()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.getOrBuild();
}
```